# How to override Bootstrap with Vue b-tab CSS style?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I'm working with Bootstrap in Vue and I have three b-tabs that I'm having trouble styling. Right now it does 
[this when the screen gets narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pJK9.png). I don't want this. I [want it to do this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7i18.png) when the widow is resized. By inspecting the elements, I found [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fiMi.png) and that by unselecting flex-wrap:wrap, it does what I want it to.

I have added

```
.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap !important;
}
```

To my style, but the display is still stacking the b-tabs when the screen narrows.

Any suggestions on how to override the Bootstrap styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired result by adding a min-width to the styling to the parent container.

Comment: be sure to mark this as the accepted answer so that future readers know it solved your problem!